# Google Calendar API: Cannot get Google Meet link while creating calendar event

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar API to add events in google calendar,but there is no google meet URL getting response from api but meeting url is missing .what is I am doing wrong here?
this is POST API I am using to create events: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?conferenceDataVersion=1
Request body:

[image: Request]

Response Body:

[image: Response]

Comment: please post your code as code and not as images

Answer (score 0):

Issue with my conferenceData i am passing request id out createRequest object.

```
"conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
        "conferenceSolutionKey": {
            "type": "hangoutsMeet"
        },
        `requestId`: `JksKJJSK1KJSK`
    }
}
```